# How I read a json array return form a webservice in java

Tags: java, arrays

i have this return from a webservice:

```
[{"id_professor":"1","nome":"Ana Paula","email":"ana@gmail.com"},{"id_professor":"2","nome":"Beatriz de Souza","email":"beatriz@gmail.com"},{"id_professor":"3","nome":"Carlos da Silva","email":"carlos@gmail.com"},{"id_professor":"4","nome":"Dion\u00edsio Mathias","email":"dionisio@gmail.com"},{"id_professor":"5","nome":"Eduardo Paiva","email":"eduardo@gmail.com"}]
```

and i like to read this jsonArray

ihave this code:

```
  URL endWeb = new URL("http://editalmais.com.br/concurso/blank_json_professor_curso/");
            HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) endWeb.openConnection();

                con.setReadTimeout(10000);
                con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
               con.setDoInput(true);
                con.setDoOutput(false);
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");


            int respCon = con.getResponseCode();

            if ( respCon < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST){

                Log.i("conexao", "Realizada com sucesso");
                strings =  new ArrayList<String>();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ( ( line = reader.readLine()) != null){

                    sb.append(line);

                }
                is.close();
```

until here it´s ok ... but i´am not getting the values.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the response from api and Parse the json as like below just pass the response as string to below method:

```
 public ArrayList<Example> getList(String json){
    ArrayList<Example> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        for (int count = 0; count<jsonArray.length(); count++){
            Example example = new Example();
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            example.setIdProfessor(jsonObject.getString("id_professor"));
            example.setEmail(jsonObject.getString("email"));
            example.setNome(jsonObject.getString("nome"));
            arrayList.add(example);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

**Example.java**

```
    public class Example {

private String idProfessor;

private String nome;

private String email;

public String getIdProfessor() {
return idProfessor;
}

public void setIdProfessor(String idProfessor) {
this.idProfessor = idProfessor;
}

public String getNome() {
return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

}
```

Comment: thanks...Now i can see the records on console but i can´t return the list ...what i am doing wrong.....the strings return is not compatible types....

Comment: I assume you are doing all this in async task's doInBackground() just call toString() on your string builder object and get this as the parameter in onPostExecute(String json) and then call above method to get a list.

Comment: My call on main activity  con.execute(url); .... and i try List<Pessoa> and show an error....